# Why define eventually bounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A sequence $(a_n)$ is called eventually bounded if $\exists N, K>0$ such that $\mid a_n \mid < K, ~\forall n>N.$
It can be proven that a sequence is eventually bounded iff it's bounded. So, the question is, why even create the definition of an eventually bounded sequence if you can do away with just bounded sequences? Or, rather, is there any significance to this definition beyond just classification in, say, spaces other than the real one?

Comment: No real significance. There may be situations where you know something about a sequence only for sufficiently large indices. Then having this concept would simplify arguments since you would not have to repeat the logic explaining why what happens early on does not matter.

Comment: You're right that "bounded sequence" and "eventually bounded sequence" are the same thing. However, sometimes we wish to be more explicit: for $M>0$ the statements "the sequence is bounded by $M$" and "the sequence is eventually bounded by $M$" mean different things. So, when we want to keep track of the bound, the term "eventually" makes a difference. Also, if you look at the definition of limit superior ($\limsup$), the concept of "eventually bounded by (some constant)" is important.

Comment: Using `|` where `\mid` should be used is a commonplace mistake, but occasionally the opposite happens.
$$
\begin{align}
& \mid a_n \mid < K, ~\forall n>N \tag 1 \\{}\\
& |a_n| < K ~ \forall n>N \tag 2
\end{align}
$$
The latter form is coded as `|a_n| < K ~ \forall n>N` and has proper horizontal spacing. (Sometimes with `|` it is necessary to use `\left|` and `\right|` even when there is no need for the delimiters to grow to larger sizes, in order to get proper horizontal spacing. But in this case there seems to be no such need.) I would  have edited to change line $(1)$ above to$\quad$

Comment: I would  have edited to change line $(1)$ above to line $(2)$ but for the fact that the moderators of math.s.e. have recently become hostile to correctness in typesetting and to people who know about that. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Should use `\lvert` and `\rvert` instead of just overloading the plain `|` when used for left and right delimiters, see AMS LaTeX doc.